# How to remove specific characters?

Tags: python, string

I want to eliminate specific characters.

I tried the `rstrip()` function in Python.

```py
a = "happy! New! Year!!!"
print(a)
b = a.lower()
print(b)
c = b.rstrip('!')
print(c)
```

This is the result.

> happy! New! Year!!!
> happy! new! year!!!
> happy! new! year

I want to output "happy new year", but the function just got rid of last three '!' characters.

Comment: It's `replace` what you looking for . `rstrip`, hence the name, strips from right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rstrip` function only strips a given character appearing one or more times at the end of the entire *string*.  To remove `!` from the end of each *word*, we can use `re.sub`:

```
a = "happy! New! Year!!!"
output = re.sub(r'\b!+(?!\S)', '', a)
print(output)  # happy New Year
```

Comment: `re` seems a bit overkill for this.

Comment: Not at all if the goal be to target only `!` appearing at the end of each word.

Comment: I would still probably split-rstrip-join, but fair enough.

Comment: Hard to tell if it's the goal or not... *I wanted to eliminate specific characters* doesn't seem to indicate consideration of words is needed though... *shrugs*

Comment: ...of course use `replace` to just blanket remove all `!` ... maybe I think too much.

Answer (score 6):

the rstrip function in python will only remove trailing characters that are specified, not all instances of the character in the string. For example if I did:

```
a = 'hello'

print(a.rstrip('l'))
```

nothing would change, because there is an e at the end of the string after any instance of 'l'

You might want to try using the replace method:

```
a = 'hello'

print(a.replace('l','')
> heo
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [answer] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). While it's good to be friendly and polite, it's better not to be conversational, since this is *not a discussion forum*. The tone we want is more FAQ-like.